# Acne underneath skin

Tags: dermatology, acne, topical-cream-gel, benzoyl-peroxide, blemishes

### Introduction

Okay, I've almost won my war. The battle, its almost won... However, I must still claim victory in my final battle. The battle against the little enemies, the ones that have fought with my blade of benzoyl peroxide *every single day.*

### Problem

Through spot treatments I have been able to fell every single one of these spots, but only the ones **on** my face. I've been using a spot treatment with benzoyl peroxide in, which has worked really well for me. However, my issue comes here:

> There are spots underneath my skin, I think. The areas where they come through are a bit red.

So, because there is still slightly red skin on my face, and I think this is causing my acne to constantly return. I need to stop this, and end my war once and for all.

### What I've tried

- Washing my face with a rag and sponge every day, three times a day
- Changing my pillow case every day
- Using a benzoyl peroxide spot treatment
- Minimizing how much I touch my face
- Not interfering with the spots with my fingers, not picking at them, not playing with them. Just letting spot creams eradicate them.

### Conclusion

Seriously, this driving me up the wall. I spot cream in the evening, by the time tomorrow has ended and its time for a shower, they've all come back. Its like they're coming in waves, damn waves! I must put an end to this.

So, how can I prevent acne from coming back within the **space of a single school day**? How can I get rid of these once and for all? What types of measures could I try? I have no reason to visit my doctor, its only acne, but I have no idea what I can try now.

*Is there even a point in me trying? I acknowledge that I am a teenager, but no others that I know seem to have acne/spots like I do.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the only real way to "get rid of acne once and for all" is through the use of the prescription medication [isotretinoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotretinoin). It works to reduce sebum production and thusly decreases the incidence of new spots.

Warning: It's a serious medication with serious side effects -- for me most notably it was severely dry skin on every inch of my body. I've also personally done 2 rounds, as the dosage on the first go was not high enough to achieve desired (permanent) effects. Having said that, after the second course of treatment my skin improved dramatically and I only get a rare tiny pimple or two each month. It was (and can be) life-changing.

Do your resarch and speak with a doctor about options available to you specific to your personal skin situation.